# Unable to Get Syntax Correct for Writing to Text File in .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages

Tags: file-io, razor-pages

It used to be simple to find the path to a folder with text files and either create and write or add to an existing file.

Now, I just can't get the syntax right.

```
var userData = firstName + "," + lastName +
    "," + email + Environment.NewLine;

var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt");
File.AppendAllText(@dataFile, userData);
result = "Information saved.";


_context.Courses_New.Add(Courses_New);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The "File." is underlined in red and so is the "Server.".

I have seen examples that mentioned adding this code to get the "environment", but I get all red saying that HomeController must have a return value. The Create page is the return value.

```
private IHostingEnvironment _env;

public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;   
}
```

The code below is at the top of my Razor Page and it uses up the return value. So no matter what I name HomeController to, it gives me an error:

```
private readonly OESAC.Models.MyDbContext _context;

public CreateModel(OESAC.Models.MyDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Supposedly I can reference the _env variable to combine a path.
Goal is to simply write success and failure to a text file during a Create row Task.

Comment: When you refer to razor page is it `cshtml.cs` file or `.cshtml` only?

Comment: no not the view, .cshtml. I am referring the .chshtml.cs code-behind file. Razor Pages don't use a controller. Fine by me. I know, there are a million arguments for and against. Everything is working fine, I just want to write a simple line to a text file. I can do this in MS Access, VBA, PHP, VB.NET, but not in Razor Page code behind. It is a simple Save process that I want to interject a write to file line or 2. thank you Mohsin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are using Razor Pages. Controllers are used for WebApi and MVC but not needed for Razor Pages. But the same principles can be applied. As long as the other classes you need are configured with Dependency Injection (DI) you can just add them onto your page model constructor. So modify CreateModel as follows:

```
private readonly OESAC.Models.MyDbContext _context;
private IHostingEnvironment _environment { get; private set; }

public CreateModel(OESAC.Models.MyDbContext context, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _context = context;
    _environment = hostingEnvironment;
}
```

Then later in a Page event you could do something like the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {        
    var webRootPath = _environment.WebRootPath;
    var dataPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "data.txt");
    ...
}
```

**Note** this will write a file in your web root which might be publically accessible and not what you want. Using a Logger might be a better approach if you are looking to record info about the inner runnings of your task (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) for more info)

Comment: Brad, you made my day. Actually I learned something that was plauging me since the start. How to add other classes into page model constructor. You saw EXACTLY what my problem was. Well, your suggestion worked, I did have to take the word "private" out of the "private IHostingEnvironment _environment { get; set; }" . Thanks a whole bunch. I'm just not a jazz musician when it comes to all this stuff. More of a rock and roll artist. People still dance to me.

Comment: And yes, using a Logger is final goal, thanks for the link. Right now, just troubleshoot one simple Save failure which I'm thinking is client not seeing validity error in small red letters.